# Best way to fix undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, nomethoderror

I am building a rails app where I have a museums page which has a feature where it displays the museum with the most exhibits. The problem is that when there are no exhibits added to the db it gives an undefined method 'museum_name'. So the problem I have is I am not sure what would be the best way to make a check that would still allow me to access the page if there are zero exhibits?

Museums controller:

```
def index
   @museums = Museum.all
   most_exhibits = Exhibit.most_exhibits
   most_exhibits.each do |museum|
   @top_museum = MuseumsHelper.get_museum_name(museum.museum_id)[0]
end
```

Helper class method being used:

```
  def self.get_museum_name(museum_id)
    Museum.where(id: museum_id)
  end
```

Display in views:

```
<%= @top_museum.museum_name %>
```

Comment: The method name `get_museum_name` is misleading. It implies that it returns a museum's name, i.e. a string. But instead, it returns an array containing the whole museum (or an empty array). Fixing those quirks makes it much easier to reason about the actual bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it depends on how you want it to be. I think the ideal solution for yours is to check `if/else` then show the content accordingly:

```
<% if @top_museum.present? %>
  <%= @top_museum.museum_name %>
<% else %>
  <span>Nothing to display</span>
<% end %>
```

Or using `try` `<%= @top_museum.try(:museum_name) %>` or if you have ruby 2.3.0 or newer you can use safe navigation operator `<%= @top_museum&.museum_name %>` ([Read more](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use try in your helper, that way it tries the query, if it fails then it returns nil

```
def self.get_museum_name(museum_id)
   Museum.try(where(id: museum_id))
end
```

Ref: https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try